# Correct interpretation of the Uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Why is it that the Uncertainty principle is always associated with some sort of measurement? Isn't it true that the uncertainty principle holds for Quantum Mechanical systems in which no measurement is performed?